# Give an expression to the decimal number given after manipulations

Tags: binary, decimal-expansion

> Given a natural number in decimal presentation $N$.
>
> Give an expression (depending on $N$ and/or $k$) to the decimal (representation at base $10$) number given after the manipulations below:
>
> $\text{(a)}:$ Converting $N$ to binary representation, and adding $k$ times $1$ from the right.
>
> $\text{(b)}:$ Converting $N$ to binary representation, and adding $1$ from the left.
>
> $\text{(c)}:$ Converting $N$ to binary representation, and adding $k$ times $1$ from the left.

My try:

$\text{(a)}:$ $N + \sum _{i=1}^k\:2(k + \lfloor \log_2N+1 \rfloor)$

$\text{(b)}:$ $N + 2^{\lfloor \log_2N+1 \rfloor} $

$\text{(c)}:$ $N + \sum _{i=1}^k\:2^{k \lfloor \log_2N+1 \rfloor}$

Please let me know if it's true.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Suppose $N=1$ and $k=2$.  What are the results you have in mind?

Comment: @lulu $\text{(a)}: 7, \text{(b)}: 3, \text{(c)}: 7$

Comment: So you want to convert back to base $10$  at the end?  You didn't say that.  Do your formulas yield those three numbers?

Comment: @lulu I wrote "give an expression to the **decimal** number given after the manipulations". I'm struggling with $\text{a}$, I'm pretty sure the other two are correct.

Comment: I'm telling you your question isn't clear, it's easy to edit it for clarity.  As you say, $a$ is certainly wrong.  $b$ is correct for this example but if I take $N=3,k=2$  I believe I get $3\to 11\to 1111\to 15$, no?  But your formula would seem to give $3+2^{\lfloor 1.585+1\rfloor}=3+2^2=7$.  Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Oh, I mixed my examples.  For b with my choices you should get $3\to 11\to 111\to 7$ so your formula is correct in this case.  Now I agree with you that $b$ is correct.

Comment: @lulu Edited the question to clarify, is it ok now? Could you give me a lead to $\text{a}$ please?

Comment: For $c$ though...now take $N=3,k=2$ as before.  This time we really do get $3\to 11\to 1111\to 15$.  But $\lfloor \log_2 3+1\rfloor=2$ so your formula yields $3+2^2+2^4\neq 15$

Comment: Your edit is fine.  Hint for $a$:  you want to add a block of the form $B_k=1^k$.  That block is $B_k=2^{k+1}-1$.   To get it in position I have to multiply by the right power of $2$.  You already know what the power is...

Comment: Sorry, again...that was a hint for $c$ not for $a$.  I seem to be incapable of keeping the three cases straight.

Comment: The hint for $a$ is very similar though.  Now I have to multiply $N$ by  $2^k$ in order to create $k$ $0's$ on the right.  Then you can just add the block $B_k$.

Comment: @lulu I'm not following.. could you please explain further?

Comment: I'm posting something below.

Comment: $a$ is totally wrong. $b$ is OK. $c$ is almost right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_k$ denote the binary block $$B_k= \underbrace {11\cdots 11}_k$$  We remark that, in base $10$, $B_k=2^k-1$.

For $a$:  we need to create $k$ zeroes on the right of the binary expression for $N$.  We do this by multiplying by $2^k$.  Then we add $B_k$.  Thus we want $$N\mapsto 2^kN+2^k-1$$

Example:  $N=5,k=2$.  Then our operation yields $$5\to 101\to 10111\to 23$$
our formula yields $$4\times 5+4-1=23$$ as desired.

$b$ is correct as it stands.

For $c$:  we need to put the block $B_k$ on the left so we have to multiply by it by $2^{L(N)}$ where $L(N)$ denotes the length of the binary expression for $N$.  Of course $L(N)=\lfloor \log_2N+1\rfloor$  so the operation we want is $$N\mapsto N+2^{\lfloor \log_2N+1\rfloor}\times \left(2^k-1\right)$$

Example:  As before, take $N=5,k=2$.  Now our operation yields $$5\to 101\to 11101\to 29$$  We remark that $\log_25 \approx 2.322$ so $L(5)=3$ (as it should) so our formula yields $$5+2^3\times 3=5+24=29$$ as desired